NextJS Zustand (server fetching)
This might be a question that's asked several times but being new to both NextJS and Zustand, I am having trouble understanding some concepts.
This is my zustand store:
import { Category } from "@/types/categories";
import { create } from "zustand";
import { persist, createJSONStorage } from "zustand/middleware";

// Define the state interface
interface CategoryStore {
  categories: Category[];
  setCategories: (categories: Category[]) => void;
}

// Create the store with middleware
export const useCategoriesStore = create<CategoryStore>()(
  persist(
    (set) => ({
      categories: [],
      setCategories: (categories) => set({ categories }),
    }),
    {
      name: "categories",
      storage: createJSONStorage(() => sessionStorage),
      skipHydration: true,
    }
  )
);

export default useCategoriesStore;

I want to fetch the data on first load and have it readily available on any component. At the moment, I fetch the data from layout.tsx and pass it into a Context, this pattern does not feel right to me. The context looks like this:
export const DataContextProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({
  categories,
  children,
}) => {
  const setCategories = useCategoryStore((state) => state.setCategories);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCategories(categories);
  }, []);

  return <>{children}</>;
};

The concern I have with the above pattern is, the data is not available in the zustand store until its set in the useEffect. What's the right approach for fetch this data into Zustand
(if possible please include caching to your answer too)
